# how to run savitzkey Golay filter on time series NDVI image

Tags: r, signals, time-series

Is there any way to run savitzky golay filter on time series NDVI image in R. I had already tried with the following code given in the package 'signal'; 
`sg <- sgolayfilt(timeseries,3,5)`. 
But it returns following error;

```
Error in if (all(is.na(x))) return(x) : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

The file "timeseries" here is a stacked raster NDVI image. Can anybody help me in this regard. 
Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: PLease read the posting guidelines, then supply the package `sgolayfilt` comes from **and** a small, reproducible dataset for us to work with.  That said, it would appear that your `x` is not something that `is.na` can work with.

Comment: Hello Carl, can you please send me your email so that I can send the stacked raster NDVI file to you to work with. I can't find the contact  in this site.

Comment: Don't upload.  **copy and paste** a small, reproducible subset of your data.

Answer (score 1):

I have 12 raster layers, then I stack them into raster stack

```
###### Load needed package
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(tiff)
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library (zoo)
library (signal)
library(timeSeries)

NDVI_STACK <- stack (jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec)
fun <- function(x) {
v=as.vector(x)
z=substituteNA(v, type="mean") # from package timeSeries
NDVI.ts2 = ts(z, start=c(2005,1), end=c(2005,12), frequency=12)
 x=sgolayfilt(NDVI.ts2, p=2, n=5, ts=30)  
NDVI.filtered <- calc(NDVI_STACK, fun, progress='text') #raster calculation process ......
```

You may need to adjust p and n depending on your data. BTW, n must be odd dimension and, from my experience, p is less than n

: [This link is very useful](https://matinbrandt.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/smoothingfiltering-a-ndvi-time-series-using-a-savitzky-golay-filter-and-r/)

I hope it could help:)